# Angular Model Driven Forms and Dictionaries

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How would one go about representing a dictionary in a model driven form, in my model I have an array of choices which display a label and two linked dropdown per choice, the values for the two dropdown once selected should be stored in a dictionary with the key being the choice id, so my model looks like this

```
const model = {
    choices: Choice[],
    logic: { [key: string]: ChoiceLogic }
}
```

How would I represent this in a model driven form and also how would I bind the data to the resulting form group?